# Javascript document.getElementById() with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

How does `document.getElementById()` handle it when there are multiple elements with the same ID? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) simply says:

> Returns a reference to the element by its ID.

In the "Notes" section of the documentation, where I would expect a mention of what should happen, all that was stated is:

> If there is no element with the given id, this function returns null.

So I decided to find out myself, and I did a test in Chrome's dev console. Here's what I got:

```
> document.write('<div id="myid"></div>')
> document.getElementById("myid")
<div id="myid"></div>
> document.write('<span id="myid"></span>')
> document.getElementById("myid")
<div id="myid"></div>
```

It appears that it only returns the first value- could someone clarify that?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique!

Comment: There's no documented behavior for how a browser behaves WRT invalid code. That said, generally they'll return the first match. The important thing to understand is that there's no guarantee of that behavior.

Comment: @cookiemonster - Large swathes of the HTML5 spec are given over to describing how a browser behaves WRT invalid code. In this case, however it is the DOM4 spec that defines how browsers treat getElementById() when there are multiple matching element IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return the first element with the ID in the document because of the way the code runs. 
Logically it is illegal for there to be two elements with the same id. So why look for another element with the same id as the one that is already found, there should only be one element with this ID. *Most* browsers scan the document from the top down, so the first element with a matching ID is returned.

Comment: As I said _Most_ browsers would scan/parse from the top down. And _most_ developers would have the browser stop at the first element with the ID because the W3C standards say that it is illegal for there to be two elements with the same ID, so technically there shouldn't be another element with the same ID, so why keep searching, it would only waste CPU.

There are some exceptions though, because _most_ doesn't mean all.

Comment: @user2864740 - For you, and everyone else here who says that the behaviour isn't defined, The [DOM Living Standard](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-nonelementparentnode-getelementbyid) and the [W3C DOM4 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-document-getelementbyid) both say "The getElementById(elementId) method must return the first element, in tree order, within the context object's tree, whose ID is elementId, or null if there is none."

Comment: @Alohci Interesting. That would make a good answer (at least wrt. going-forward expectations).

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for all browsers, but I've been able to use the same ID multiple times only if they are a child of a uniquely ID'd item:

```
<div id="parent1">
    <div id="item"></div>
</div>
<div id="parent2">
    <div id="item"></div>
</div>
```

I could always access each individually if I included their parent name (using jQuery)

```
$("#parent1 #item") and $("#parent2 #item")
```

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers may return different things because having duplicate IDs is not valid HTML in the first place!

This is undefined behavior.

Comment: I know that having duplicate IDs is invalid, and I'm not saying that I do this in my code... but aren't browsers supposed to be "forgiving" to bad code?

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 Yes, kinda... well, they'll accept stuff like `<b><i>text</b></i>` I think, but you can only go so far...

Answer (score 0):

MDN doesn't say what happens because that's illegal in the first place.

IDs must be **unique**.

Comment: True (obviously), but could you also cite the source for that, to strengthen your statement.